# Why does sleeping between iterations causes operations in a loop to take longer than the case where it does not sleep

Tags: java

The attached program (see at the end), when executed, yields the following output:

```
..........
with sleep time of 0ms
  times= [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
  average= 0.7
..........
with sleep time of 2000ms
  times= [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
  average= 1.9
```

In both cases the exact same code is executed which is to repeatedly get the next value from a  Random object instantiated which at the start of the program. The warm up method executed first is supposed to  trigger any sort of JIT otimizations before the actual testing begins.

Can anyone explain the reason for this difference? I have been able to repeat this result in my machine every time so far, and this was executed on a multi-core Windows system with java 7.

One interesting thing is that if the order in which the tests are executed is reversed, that is, if we run the loop with the delay before the loop without the delay, then the timings are more  similar (with the no delay loop actually taking longer):

```
..........
with sleep time of 2000ms
  times= [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
  average= 2.0
..........
with sleep time of 0ms
  times= [2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
  average= 2.6
```

As much as I could tell, no object is being created inside the operation method, and when running this through a profiler it does not seem that garbage collection is ever triggered. A wild guess is that some value gets cached in a processor-local cache which gets flushed out when the thread is put to sleep and then when the thread wakes up it needs to retrieve the value from main memory, but that is not so fast. That however does not explain why inverting the order makes a difference...

The real-life situation where I initially observed this behavior (which prompted me to write this sample test class) was XML unmarshalling, where I noticed that unmarshalling the same document repeated times one after the other in quick succession yielded better times than performing the same thing but with a delay between calls to unmarshal (delay generated through sleep or manually).

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        warmUp(10000);

        int numRepetitions = 10;
        runOperationInALoop(numRepetitions, 0);
        runOperationInALoop(numRepetitions, 2000);
    }

    private static void runOperationInALoop(int numRepetitions, int sleepTime) throws InterruptedException
    {
        List<Long> times = new ArrayList<Long>(numRepetitions);
        long totalDuration = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<numRepetitions; i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

            long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            someOperation();
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;

            times.add(duration);
            totalDuration = totalDuration + duration;

            System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.println();

        double averageTimePerOperation = totalDuration/(double)numRepetitions;

        System.out.println("with sleep time of " + sleepTime + "ms");
        System.out.println("  times= " + times);
        System.out.println("  average= " + averageTimePerOperation);
    }

    private static void warmUp(int warmUpRepetitions)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<warmUpRepetitions; i++)            
        {
            someOperation();
        }
    }

    public static int someInt;
    public static Random random = new Random(123456789L);

    private static void someOperation()
    {
        for(int j=0; j<50000; j++)
        {
            someInt = ((int)random.nextInt()*10) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you sleep for even a short period of time (you may find that 10 ms is long enough) you give up the CPU and the data, instruction and branch prediction caches are disturbed or even cleared. Even making a system call like System.currentTimeMillis() or the much more accurate System.nanoTime() can do this to a small degree.

AFAIK, The only way to avoid giving up the core is to busy wait and using thread affinity to lock your thread to a core. This prevent minimises such a disturbance and means your program can runs 2-5x faster in low latency situations i.e. when sub-millisecond tasks matter.

For your interest

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/java-thread-affinity-support-for-hyper.html

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/how-much-difference-can-thread-affinity.html

Comment: That makes sense, and I suppose my wild guess wasn't too off the mark after all. However it is still not immediately clear why the "no sleep" version of the loop shows the same (worse) performance when it is executed after the "with sleep" version. Thanks for the links!

Comment: "The only way to avoid giving up the core is to busy wait" - a thread doing busy wait could still be preemptively scheduled out by the scheduler, no? That would still cause context switching and processor cache changes, as I understand it. Need to investigate more how thread affinity locks work.

Comment: On Linux you can tell the scheduler to isolate particular cpus. If you use thread affinity to assign one thread to an isolated CPU it won't be pre-empted by another thread.

Comment: Accepting this as answer although it is still a mystery to me why the order of the execution of the loops matter.

Answer (score 2):

When you're thread goes to sleep you're essentially saying to the JVM: This thread is doing nothing for the next X milliseconds. The JVM is likely at that point to wake up various background threads to do their thing (GC, for example), which may well cause updates to data stored in the processor cache. When you're thread reawakes, some of its data may no longer be in the cache (fast), but may well be shifted out to main memory (slow).

Take a look at http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/ for more discussion of low level caching effects.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no guarantee that `sleep()` sleeps for exactly the length of time you specify. There is a specific statement in the Javadoc to that effect.
2. `System.currentTimeMillis()` has a system-dependeny granularity which you are exposing by running such relatively few iterations as 2000. You should multiply that by at least 10 to get out of the granularity region. On Windows I believe it is as high as 16ms.

Comment: 1. The amount of time the thread sleeps it not particularly important. From previous responses, it seems like it just needs to be long enough to cause the thread to give up the core it is running on.

Comment: 2. From the numbers I got (and their consistency) seems like I am above the the granularity. Even when switching to System.nanoTime() and got even better precision, so I'm inclined to say that this is not adversely affecting the tests, in this case.

Comment: @jsiqueira Eh? 'The amount of time the thread sleeps' is the only thing at issue in this question. If it sleeps for longer than the time you specify, you will get the behaviour you have observed.

Comment: I don't get it how the thread sleeping more than the time I specified is the cause for the behavior I observed. Seems like the behavior is observed in any occasion where the thread sleeps enough to relinquish the core it was on, regardless of whether that time is less, equal or more than the time specified in the source code.